Application Load Balancer Custom Routing Rule YAML Format
I am trying to create a custom routing rule for my application load balancer.
I have a default rule that is working. The rule forwards everything coming to domain.com/ > domain.com/links
Now I am trying to create ANOTHER rule that will forward everything going to domain.com/links to an external site.....
what do I put for the "defaultService" field... I cannot figure out what google expects here.
defaultService:
name: matcher1
routeRules:

matchRules:

prefixMatch: /links
priority: 1
urlRedirect:
hostRedirect: extdomain.com
pathRedirect: /URL
redirectResponseCode: FOUND,
stripQuery: True



In the "defaultService" field I tried
domain.com
www.domain.com
global/net-services/loadbalancing/LOADBALANCERNAME

Based from this documentation the instruction shows that for defaultService you should place  global/backendServices/BACKEND\_SERVICE\_1
In case the link fails, you can follow this yaml from the documentation.

   defaultService: global/backendServices/BACKEND_SERVICE_1
   name: global-lb-map
   hostRules:
   - hosts:
     - '*'
     pathMatcher: matcher1
   pathMatchers:
   - defaultService: global/backendServices/BACKEND_SERVICE_1
     name: matcher1
     routeRules:
       - matchRules:
           - prefixMatch: /PREFIX
         priority: PRIORITY  # 0 is highest
         urlRedirect:
           hostRedirect: "new-host-name.com" # Omit to keep the requested host
           pathRedirect: "/new-path" # Omit to keep the requested path; mutually exclusive to prefixRedirect
           prefixRedirect: "/newPrefix" # Omit to keep the requested path; mutually exclusive to pathRedirect
           redirectResponseCode: FOUND
           stripQuery: True


